# Counterexample about composition of function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, examples-counterexamples

**Problem :**

Assume that two functions $f(x), g(x)$ are differentiable function.

(And, no one of them has interval which makes them constant function.)

And consider a function $f(x)$ has local maxima(or local minima) at $x=a$.

Then $f(g(x))$ also at $g(x)=a$?

---

I saw a function which as oscillation property works well for counterexample about increasing/decreasing and local maximum, minimum.

And, It also works if I switch the problem for 'if $g$ has local max, $f(g)$ also?'

The counterexample for switched problem is :

$$f(x)=x^2\left(1+ \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right),\quad f(0)=0 \\ 
g(x)=x^2$$

Then we know $g$ has local minimum at $x = 0$ but $f(g(x))$ isn't.

So, I wonder how can I find a counterexample about the original problem?

Or, I want to know the proof about original problem if that's true.

Thanks for help.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2, g(x)=x, a=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $f(x)$ has a local maximum at $x=a$, it means that you can choose $r>0$ so that $f(a)\geq f(x)$ whenever $x\in(a-r,a+r)$.

Suppose $g(c)=a$. Because $g$ is continuous, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $g(x)\in(a-r,a+r)$ whenever $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$.

Therefore, for such $\delta$ and for $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$, you have $f(a)\geq f(g(x))$.

So $f(g(x))$ has a local maximum at $x=c$.

Comment: Should I use inverted inequality for local minimum case, right?

Comment: yes that is correct